# after axios interceptors return on error res is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jwt, interceptor

Hello I'm making a Reactjs app (with laravel backend) that uses jwt tokens to authenticate. I want to refresh the jwt token when the token has expired or is invalid (401 response). But the response is undefined in the show function when it goes through the error inteceptor.

(axios request function)

```
    show() {
        axios.get("/api/company/show/" + this.props.user.company_id)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            const company = res.data
            this.setState({
                company
            })
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
```

(interceptor response)

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
      console.log(response)
    return response
  },
...
```

if the token is valid the request returns a normal response and it works,

but when laravel returns a 401 error it does not work.

(laravel)

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        try {
            $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Token is Invalid.'], 401);
            } else if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Token has Expired.'], 401);

            } else {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Authorization Token not found.'], 401);
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

(interceptor error)

```
...
  (error) => {
      console.log('error')
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const originalRequest = error.config
      console.log(originalRequest.headers.Authorization)
      const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('token')
      if (error.response && (error.response.status === 401 || error.response.status===500) && error.config && !error.config.__isRetryRequest && refreshToken) {
        originalRequest._retry = true

        const response = fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_PATH+'api/auth/refresh', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${refreshToken}`
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            refresh: refreshToken,
          }),
        })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then(res=>{
            console.log(res.token)
            localStorage.setItem("token", res.token)
            axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${res.token}`
            originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${res.token}`
            return axios(originalRequest)
            })
        resolve(response)
      }

      return Promise.reject(error)
    }).then(()=>console.log('done refreshing'));
  },
)
```

The interceptor error will request a new token. Then the original call will be requested again with the new token.
The new request response is visible in the interceptor (response) => {...} but not in the show() function

[image: console.log]
first line is the console.log in the interceptor (response)
third line is the console.log in the show() function
and the error is that it can't find 'data' `const company = res.data` in the show() function

So the problem is that if I get a 401 error the request is undefined in the show() function (and other function to)

Comment: did you ever sort this out ?

Comment: Did you even figure this out? I'm having the same problem over here and it's driving me nuts...